# Difference between 'transport' and 'delivery'

Tags: meaning

> I'll be in charge of **the transport,**|and you **the deliveries**, all right?

What is difference between 'transport' and 'delivery' in this sentence?

That line from drama about drug cartel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Transport**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transport):

> to transfer or convey from one place to another

[**Deliver**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliver):

> to take and hand over to or leave for another : convey · *deliver* a package

In other words, one person drives the truck that takes the package from one place to another, while another actually hands the package to the recipient.